Shortcut Copy/Paste not working (VB.Net, Winforms)
I'm debugging a program. We have a custom control mainly for text input use, it has only a base form, a textbox and a tooltip. What I'm debugging is the fact a specific form is using this control but only and specifically in this form Ctrl+C/V do not work. Other shortcuts work. Right-click works.
I made some tests and A+B get detected, Ctrl THEN V get detected, Ctrl+A get detected. Only Ctrl+C/V seem to be disabled somehow. My doubt is now if there are ways to specifically prevent these shortcuts. I read this post
how can i forbid the copy/paste option of a textbox in vb.Net?
and I tried searching in the whole solution for Pasting or for e.Handled but nothing takes me to a solution involving this situation. I wondered if there could be some property for the textbox preventing only these 2 shortcuts but it seems not.
Also, I found out something strange. When I try to press these keys there seems to be a Console.Write("aaaa") and I searched the whole solution for Console.Write but I found nothing that could take me locate that. I tried to set a breakpoint in the few occurrences for console but none gets triggered.


I would search for "aaaa" in the solution instead for "Console.Write". You didn't provide details, but it could be written by Debug.Write.



I would check if there is any Control.PreProcessMessage used in the parent form. Similarly Control.ProcessCmdKey and Control.WndProc. They all can process key press and ignore specific combinations.


I'll have to check tomorrow. I didn't mention aaaa because it seemed kinda too obvious.

Definitely it was a Debug.Write command, writes "aa" and gets triggered twice. Thank you!

I kinda fixed this. In short, the situation when I had this bug was due to another control of the form which, although not visible as it is part of a tabgroup structure and it's located in another tabpage, detected copy/paste by keyboard and was handled in this specific situation to prevent them working. Since I still need to handle that control in a very specific manner, in the end I disabled the way that control detects copy/paste by keyboard shortcuts (it's a special control, actually, it has its own feature to use shortcuts) and instead I'm handling generally these shortcuts only when the control is actually used by handling KeyDown event. So they work when I actually need to use that control, they don't get detected when I'm working in another tabpage and, in the latter case, I can use them on other controls.
